# Error display in the django admin through save_model

Tags: django, forms, signals, validationerror

I have the following code in one of the classes related to the admin page:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if change:
        if form.initial['delivered'] != form.cleaned_data['delivered']:
            for line in obj.lines.all():
                book = line.book

                if not book.is_available and not obj.delivered:
                    raise ValidationError('Error')

                if obj.delivered:
                    number = line.book.number + 1
                    line.book.is_available = True
                else:
                    number = book.number - 1
                    if not number:
                        book.is_available = False
                line.book.number = number
                line.book.save()
    obj.save()
    return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

The problem is that when the code reaches the `raise ValidationError('Error')` line and is executed, it doesn't show the error on the page and shows it like django debug errors, and this error is displayed only when `DEBUG=True`. How can I show this error like the django admin form errors?

I also tried this code with django signals but it had the same result.
Only when I wrote a class form myself and gave it to the admin class, it displayed the error correctly, but I cannot implement the conditions here in the form class. Is there a way to fix it in the `save_model`?[image]

Answer (score 1):

you may try with (not tested):

```
raise form.ValidationError('Error')
```

Comment: I had tried it:
'LendForm' object has no attribute 'ValidationError'

Comment: you can try change_view.

`def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        try:
            return super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
        except ValidationError as e:
            # Display the validation error as a form error in the admin
            errors = {'__all__': [str(e)]}
            form = self.get_form(request, obj=None)
            form._errors = errors
            return self.render_change_form(request, form, change=True, context=extra_context)`